# How to install NeoVim v0.9.5 on Debian, by means of downloading the tarball file, unpacking it and running ./nvim-linux64/bin/nvim?

Tags: debian, software-installation, nvim

I'm asking this, because I need to install NeoVim from [github](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.9.5) to get the latest 0.9.5 version instead of the v0.7.something available via `apt` package manager.

```
$ sudo apt list neovim
Listing... Done
neovim/stable 0.7.2-7 amd64
```

But I rarely install software manually, so I have no idea where exactly (what location) should I choose to install NeoVim manually [in the following manner](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.9.5):
Install NeoVim from tarball file:

1. Download `nvim-linux64.tar.gz` (**yes, but into what exact location am I supposed 2 download this file?**)
2. Extract: `tar xzvf nvim-linux64.tar.gz` (**yes, but into what exact location am I supposed 2 extract this file?**)
3. Run `./nvim-linux64/bin/nvim` (**what exact dir is represented by the "." in this path?**)

I'm going to install this NeoVim onto Debian 12, virtual private server, no graphical environment.

```
$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: debian
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm 
  Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
          Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Vultr
  Hardware Model: HFC
```

And it's important for me, that this NeoVim opens easily, using `nvim` command and not some cumbersome and long, full path and filename invocation.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I want to install NeoVim system-wide, so that all the users can use it, the same way they're using any other program.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, distributions backport feature updates into packages and keep the release numbers the same (they almost always backport security patches). In those cases, that's all you need. Neovim isn't one of these cases and doesn't have all of the latest features. I'm just pointing that out for future reference.

For what is on Github, you can either:

1. Compile it first using the instructions on the page. You'll need to compile it in a directory to which all users have access.
2. Use the pre-compiled binary that you've acquired.

After you've done that, you'll need sudoer rights which it sounds like you have in order to add it to the init so that it is prepended to the path where the `neovim` binary is located whether you compile it from source or use the pre-compiled binaries. For example, if it is `/usr/local/neovim/0.9.5/bin`, then create a file in `/etc/profile.d` such as `/etc/profile.d/neovim.sh` with the following contents:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/neovim/0.9.5/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure that the init file above is world readable and that the path to where you place the binaries is world-accessible. That will add it to the environment of every user at login who is using `bash` as their login shell.

Comment: Yes. I have sudo rights. I'm the admin of this server, just not a very skillful one :-) Can you please explain in little more detail, why do you advise me to compile the NeoVim from source (which I don't feel I'm capable of doing) instead of pointing me the location, where the extracted NeoVim directory (from the tarball file) should be copied to (for example ```/usr/local/``` or ```/usr/bin/```? I don't feel like I'll be able to compile NeoVim from the source. ```init``` is a file of some kind??

Comment: “Most distributions backport feature updates into packages and keep the release numbers the same so the `neovim` in the repositories most likely has all of the features as the latest from Github.” — I’m not sure where you got that impression, but that’s simply not true. Distributions backport important bug fixes; the only exception is, in some distributions, the kernel, which gets features backported (*e.g.* in RHEL). Debian‘s `neovim` 0.7.2 packages don’t contain new features from later releases.

Comment: @StephenKitt There are packages that do. I recognized that there are packages where this may not be the case which is why I also included instructions for that from Github. I'll update my answer to better cover this.

Comment: @michalroesler Force of habit. I always compile from source even when the binaries are available. I also saw instructions on the page so it went along with what I usually do. I've included using the pre-compiled binary. You can use the same method.